# Joining two files based on two fields

Tags: perl, join, awk

I posted a question before a week and the answer was simply (use join):

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) >output
```

to join files that have something common which is usually the first field.

I have the following two files:

genes.txt

```
ENSG001 ENSG002
ENSG002 ENSG001
ENSG003 ENSG004
```

features.txt

```
ENSG001 400
ENSG002 350
ENSG003 210
ENSG004 100
```

I need to join these two files to be like this:

output.txt

```
ENSG001 400 ENSG002 350
ENSG002 350 ENSG001 400
ENSG003 210 ENSG004 100
```

I know the answer is in join command but I can't figure out how to join based on two fields. I tried

`join -j 1 <(sort genes.txt) <(sort features.txt) >attempt1.txt`

but the result will looks like this:

attempt1.txt

```
ENSG001 ENSG002 400
ENSG002 ENSG001 350
ENSG003 ENSG004 210
```

I then tried

`join -j 2 <(sort -k 2 genes.txt) <(sort -k 2 features.txt) >attempt2.txt`

attempt2.txt is empty

Does (join) have the ability to join two files based on two fields ? If no then how can I do it ?

Comment: Should ENST in features.txt be ENSG, maybe?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `Perl`? You are asking a question about `join`.

Comment: I have answered my question. Thanks all for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all guys I have managed to answer it by tricking the problem.

First I joined the files normally, I then changed the position of first and second field, I next joined the modified output file another time with features, and finally I switched the positions of fields again.

```
join <(sort genes.txt) <(sort features.txt) >tmp

cat tmp | awk '{ print $2, $1, $3 }' >tmp2

join <(sort tmp2) <(sort features.txt) >tmp3

cat tmp3 | awk '{ print $2, $3, $1, $4 }' >output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
%features;
open $fd, '<', 'features.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fd>) {
    ($k, $v) = split;
    $features{$k} = $v;
}
close $fd or die $!;

open $fd, '<', 'genes.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fd>) {
    s/(\w+)/$1 $features{$1}/g;
    print;
}
close $fd or die $!;
```

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, join does NOT support this. See [`join manpage`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/join/).

However, you can accomplish this in 2 ways:

- Turn the first space/tab in the file into a caret (or other character you will never see in the file), then use join as before which will treat the first 2 fields as 1 field:

  ```
  perl -pi -e 's/^(\S+)\s+/$1#/' file1
  perl -pi -e 's/^(\S+)\s+/$1#/' file2
  join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) >output
  tr "#" " " output > output.final
  ```
- Do it in Perl. You can do

  - the blunt approach (perreal's answer: slurp in 2 files at once); this takes a lot of memory if both files are large
  - The more memory conserving approach (cdtits's answer: slurp in a smaller file, store in a hash, then apply the lookups to line-by-line read of second file)
  - For really gynormous files, do a linear approach:

    sort both files, read 1 line of each file; if they match, print the match; if not; skip 1 line in the file whose ID was smaller.

Answer (score 1):

In case that "ENST" in features.txt is "ENSG", here is an **awk** solution that works well on given example:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while(getline <"features.txt") f[$1]=$2} {print $1,f[$1],$2,f[$2]}' < genes.txt
```

I can explain in detail if you need to.

Comment: +1 - Or `awk 'FNR == NR {f[$1] = $2; next} {print $1, f[$1], $2, f[$2]}' features.txt genes.txt`. Note that the redirection you have at the end isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open GIN, "<genes.txt"    or die("genes");
open FIN, "<features.txt" or die("features");
my %relations;
my %values;
while (<GIN>) {
  my ($r1, $r2) = split;
  $relations{$r1} = $r2;
}
while (<FIN>) {
  my ($k, $v) = split;
  $values{$k} = $v;
}
for my $r1 (sort keys %relations) {
  my $r2 = $relations{$r1};
  print "$r1 $values{$r1} $r2 $values{$r2}\n"; 
}
close FIN; close GIN;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is generally right. It should be achievable by something like

```
join -o '1.1 2.2 1.2 1.3' <(
    join -o '1.1 1.2 2.2' -1 2 <(sort -k 2 genes.txt) <(sort features.txt) |
    sort
) <(sort features.txt)
```

If I place `ENSG004` instead of `ENST004` into `features.txt` I will get exactly what you are looking for:

```
$ join -o '1.1 2.2 1.2 1.3' <(
      join -o '1.1 1.2 2.2' -1 2 <(sort -k 2 genes.txt) <(sort features.txt) |
      sort
  ) <(sort features.txt)
ENSG001 400 ENSG002 350
ENSG002 350 ENSG001 400
ENSG003 210 ENSG004 100
```

There is less verbose version but there is harder to keep track of fields:

```
join -o '1.2 2.2 1.1 1.3' -1 2 <(
    join -1 2 <(sort -k 2 genes.txt) <(sort features.txt) |
    sort -k 2
) <(sort features.txt)
```

If you are going process really big data it will should work pretty effective to tens of GB (and also should be better then most of RDBMS's if `features.txt` and `genes.txt` are comparable in size):

```
TMP=`mktemp`
sort features.txt > "$TMP"
sort -k 2 genes.txt | join -o '1.1 1.2 2.2' -1 2 - "$TMP" | sort |
    join -o '1.1 2.2 1.2 1.3' - "$TMP"
rm "$TMP"
```

Comment: What does join -o '1.1 2.2 1.2 1.3' means ?

Comment: @LocaToney: According to the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/join-invocation.html) it defines output formatting. Particularly `-o '1.1 2.2 1.2 1.3'` means that the first output column will be the first column from the first input file, the second column will be the second column from the second file, the third one will be the second column from the first file and the last fourth column will be the third column from the first file.